# Is there a countable $X\subseteq 2^{\omega}$ such that for any uncountable $Y\subseteq 2^{\omega}$, we have $X\cap Y\not=\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm curious if there is a "small" set that nonetheless manages to meet every uncountable subset of $2^{\omega}$, or if that's just a pipe dream.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets meeting your conditions, then $Y-X$ would be an uncountable set (since only a countable number of elements were removed) and $X\cap (Y-X) =\emptyset$

Comment: Excellent. Thanks